# Assembly Language - Counting Number of Lower & Uppercase Letters

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

I am trying to write a program in C with in-line assembly in Visual Studio. I am reading in a string and need to store the number of lowercase characters in a variable and the number of uppercase characters in a variable. Here is what I have thus far:

```
void FnlUpperLowerCount(char *inStr) {

    int UpCount =  -99;

    int LowCount = -99;

    _asm {

        mov esi, inStr

        mov al, [esi]

    }

    printf("The number of upper case letters   : %d\n",UpCount);

    printf("The number of lower case letters   : %d\n",LowCount);

    return ;

}
```

I am not really sure how to go further.

Comment: I would write it first in C, from then it should be rather straightforward to convert it to asm.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact syntax I have to use but I believe it should look like this.
Well I also assumed that inStr is a null terminated sequence of only alphabetical characters

```
void FnlUpperLowerCount(char *inStr) {

int UpCount =  0;

int LowCount = 0;

_asm {

    mov esi, inStr

    loop:

    mov al, [esi]

    or al,al

    jz finished

    cmp al,91

    jc capital

    inc LowCount

    jmp cont

    capital:

    inc Upcount

    cont:

    inc esi

    jmp loop

    finished:

}

printf("The number of upper case letters   : %d\n",UpCount);

printf("The number of lower case letters   : %d\n",LowCount);

return ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mov esi,inStr   ;To start off initialize  esi point to input string
mov edi,outStr  ;edi point to the output string area

incr:
    mov [edi],al
    add edi,1
    add esi,1
    mov al,[esi]
    inc ecx
    jmp contf

startf:

    mov al,[esi]
    mov ecx,0

contf:

    cmp al,7bh
    jl isdone
    jmp incr

greater1:

    cmp al,61h
    jl incr
    sub al,20h
    jmp incr

isdone:

    cmp al,0
    jg greater1

done:

    mov outStr,edi
```